# does h2 database support prefix index?

Tags: indexing, h2, prefix, database-indexes

I have a table with a TEXT/CLOB like column that need to be indexed:

```
CREATE TABLE test (id INT PRIMARY KEY, val VARCHAR(512))
```

but this index takes too much spaces:

```
CREATE INDEX test_val ON test(val)
```

Can I create an index with only a prefix of this column? like MySQL's prefix index:

```
CREATE INDEX test_val ON test(val(20))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

H2 does not support partial indexes in any way. Here is the related feature request:
https://github.com/h2database/h2database/issues/2054

H2 supports indexes on generated columns, so you can create a generated column based on your original column (`AS SUBSTRING(ORIGINAL_COLUMN FROM 1 FOR 20)`) and index it, but you will be required to specify the value of this column in your `SELECT` queries; otherwise its index will not be used.